# High refresh rate monitor locked to 60hz when dual monitor setup

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, xorg, display, display-resolution

OS: Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS

I recently got a new external Monitor for my Laptop. It supports AMD Freesync, and has a refresh rate of 165hz, and a size of 1080x1920. The built in monitor is 60hz and also 1080x1920.

I connect my laptop to my monitor using a Mini-Display port cable. The high refresh rate works fine if only the external monitor is in use, but if I join or mirror the displays it all goes downhill and both monitors are at 60hz.

Fun fact: while the movement of windows and everything else is at 60hz, the mouse cursor remains very smooth.

I am on Xorg and Nvidia Graphics Card